# Manual copy of git repo renames itself after programm restart

Tags: wordpress, git

I'm developing 2 Wordpress plugins, one called **wheels**, the other **tires**. These are cpt plugins to show wheels and tires, and I'm using Git on Bitbucket, where these 2 repos have their home.

**The situation:**
I have made a handish copy of the "wheels" plugin (explorer > copied files, new folder, pasted in the files).

After that, I did rename the files, because the structure of the plugins is basically the same. (Custom post type, taxonomies, archive page etc..). I have been pretty accurate with the renaming of all functions and filenames.

Then, I have set up **a brand new repository** on bitbucket and pushed the renamed files/the plugin **tires** to it.

So far so good, **my problem**:

After restarting BitBucket, the plugin tires renames itself back again to wheels, resulting in the situation, that I have two repos in Bitbucket, which are both called **wheels**.

The files stay different from each other, everything works fine (pushing new code to each of the repositories works, on the BitBucket website the naming of the repositories is correct, new files/new code gets recognized uploaded to Bitbucket).

[image: Bitbucket view]

As I wrote before,

**After restarting BitBucket for Windows / my PC, the tires plugin renames itself to wheels.**

Looking through every file of the tires plugin, everything looks correct (not a single time is the word wheels contained in any of the files). I have also had a look at the .git folder and the files in it. Every thing is named/worded after *tires* not *wheels*.

I can't grasp why it is doing that. I did google and search before, but the problem is hard to describe and formulate as a searchphrase in my opinion.

Please help me, this is making me mad.

Comment: Is it me, or is that Sourcetree as opposed to "BitBucket for Windows"? Can you just delete the repository from Sourcetree and add it again? Then you can specify the proper name.

Comment: I already did that 3 times with the hope that it will fix it - after a restart of SourceTree (closing application or restarting windows) it renames itself. Thank you for the hint.